# Laravel не работает переадресация

Tags: php, laravel

Заполняю форму по адресу `/zakaz/zayavka/otbor`. После отправки должно редиректится по адресу `/zakaz/zayavka/otbor/obrazez`. В роутах вроде бы всё прописано. Но в итоге получаю ошибку `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`. И вообще не понимаю, в чём дело. Если поменять роут и редирект в контроллере на самого себя, то есть вместо `obrazez` написать `otbor`, он без ошибок редиректится сам на себя по первому адресу `/zakaz/zayavka/otbor`. Что не так?

Роуты

```html
Route::get('/zakaz/zayavka/otbor/obrazez', function () {
    return view('obrazez');
});
Route::post('/zakaz/zayavka/otbor/submit','OtborController@submit')->name('obrazez');
```

Форма

```html
 <form action="/zakaz/zayavka/otbor/submit" method="post">
   @csrf
      ......
      <button type="submit">
   {{ __('Отправить') }}
     </button>
   </form>
```

Контроллер

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Otbor;
use Auth;

class OtborController extends Controller
{
    public function submit (Request $req)
    {

      $zayav=new Otbor();

      $zayav->id_zayav=$req->input('id_zayav');
      $zayav->data=$req->input('data');
      $zayav->mesto=$req->input('mesto');
      $zayav->save();
      return redirect()->route('obrazez')->with( ['zayav' => $zayav] );

    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('obrazez');
    }

}
```

Comment: Попробуйте написать POST вместо post для method [формы](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Маршрут с именем `obrazez` - это `/zakaz/zayavka/otbor/submit` для POST запроса.
 Об этом и говорится в сообщении об ошибке.

Перенесите `->name('obrazez')` из второго маршрута в первый:

```
Route::get('/zakaz/zayavka/otbor/obrazez', function () {
    return view('obrazez');
})->name('obrazez');
Route::post('/zakaz/zayavka/otbor/submit','OtborController@submit');
```