# Не работает переадресация в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Когда пытаюсь перейти на страницу по ссылке(кнопке) вылетает ошибка `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`. Вроде бы в другом файле(сайте) и роуты 1 в 1, и контроллер и форма, но там такой ошибки нет. Как исправить?

Контроллер

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Botinkes;

class Controller2 extends Controller
{
    public function submit (Request $req)
    {

      $zayav=new Botinkes();
      $zayav->adr=$req->input('poisk');



      return redirect()->route('poisk1');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        return view('poisk1');
    }
}
```

Форма

```html
<form action="/submit" method="post">
            @csrf
          <input type="text" id="poisk" name="poisk">
          <button type="submit">Поиск</button>
</form>
```

Роуты

```html
Route::get('/botinok', function () {
    return view('poisk1');

});
Route::post('/submit','Controller2@submit')->name('poisk1');
```

Comment: ответ такой же, как и прошлый раз: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122344/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Laravel не работает переадресация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122344/laravel-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: В прошлый раз помогло, сейчас не помогает.

Comment: Точнее если перенести ->name('poisk1') в первый роут, начинает писать что view с именем poisk1 не найден

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь сделать запрос на метод, который редиректит на POST роут, что не совсем понятно для чего. Предполагается что редирект будет делаться на GET роут. Да и вообще не понятна логика, получается что вы циклите запрос навечно.